# Getting user input for parameters then draw shape C#

Tags: c#, forms, geometry, draw

[Pic of Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi1fS.png)

I am trying to get input from the user to set the x, y coordinates to the DrawEllipse function, when i hard code the values into it it draws a circle on the screen just fine however when i try passing in a int that has come from user input it doesn't work.

I am trying to make a program that responds to commands from users e.g. the user can type in "draw shape x y".
The string is being split when a space is detected the string is split into an array.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String input;
    Bitmap drawOutput;

    String command, command2, command3;
    int x, y;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        drawOutput = new Bitmap(OutputBox.Size.Width, OutputBox.Size.Height);
        OutputBox.Image = drawOutput;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g;
        g = Graphics.FromImage(drawOutput);

        Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.Dispose();
    }

    private void CMDBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input = CMDBox.Text;
    }

    private void ExecuteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] spilt = input.Split(' ');
        foreach (String words in spilt)
        {
            command = spilt[0];
            command2 = spilt[1];
            command3 = spilt[2];

            x = Int32.Parse(command2);
            y = Int32.Parse(command3);



            Graphics g;
            g = Graphics.FromImage(drawOutput);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

            if (input == command)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(pen, 0, 0, x, y);

                OutputBox.Image = drawOutput;

                g.Dispose();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Um, what exactly is the question?

Comment: how do i draw a shape using a number that is chosen by the user? e.g. user can type draw 100 100. Then the x and y coords will be set to that and then drawn on screen. Only works right know when it is hard coded in

Comment: `if (input == command)` will always return false since command is a part of input...

Comment: If this is a WinForm, not an HTML form, you need to get a book or tutorial because that is not how to draw into a WinForm.

Comment: `if (input == command)` should be `if (command == "draw")` or maybe "circle" etc..

Comment: Do yourself a favor and write out the full grammar you want to implement, maybe like so: [draw|fill] [rect|ellispe] x y w h color